# Audio smooth / enhance algorithm, software

Tags: audio, audio-processing, software-implementation, enhancement

Years ago I was working with a sound editor program called Sony Sound Forge. It had this filter of smooth/enhance which I liked and used a lot, but now I can't find such filter in Adobe Audition or Audacity. Unfortunately that editor is not available on linux and windows version is beyond my budget. So I wonder if:

- Is that filter available in Audacity but I can't find it? (or perhaps as a plugin)?
- How, if possible at all, can I define a custom filter that does the same job, either in Audacity or Adobe Audition?

here's a brief quote:

> The Enhance function boosts the very highest frequencies (close to the
> Nyquist frequency) in the sound file, making the sound file sound more
> vivid. It is useful for compensating for the effects of downsampling
> or for bringing out very fast transients in a sound file.

But it's not simply a parametric or graphic EQ.

[link for more info](http://soundforge.helpmax.net/en/batchengine-chmbatchengine-hhc/processes/smoothenhance/), just in case.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not familiar with the filter but have you tried to perform a simple frequency analysis (this idea stems from the fact that the filter developers state that all it does is to boost high frequencies) to see the difference "before and after"? If this is indeed such as "simple" filter operation then you could possibly reverse engineer it and implement your own filter.

Comment: Sounds like a "sharpening" filter.

Comment: @ZaellixA unfortunately as told before I no loger can use it. I still have many files that I did perform the filter on them but not the original ones. so cant do any comparison. Plus, all it does isn't boost high frqs, bc I can't replicate that with Eq and even Eq+compressor. If you read the linked page, it also smooth out the glitches.

Comment: @Royi yes, more or less I can relate "sharpening" to that, like sharpen/blur. it either increases the fast transitions amplitude or makes them faster (in enhance side) but don't know how, and on the smooth side it reduces them by amplitude and/or modifying the  samples around sudden big jump values (like 1st sample -x next one +y) that will be heard as a click sound.

Comment: @Royi I guess (but not sure) that applying the smooth on a square , sawtooth, or triangle waveform will eventually be sine. but on enhance side have no idea what will really happen.

Comment: @user174174 I did read the info in the link but from my understanding the implementation may be rather complicated. On one hand the "sharpening" part of the filter sounds like what Royi suggested and on the other hand, the smoothing part sounds like...... smoothing (duh!), which can be achieved in various ways. Unfortunately I am not aware of **one** filter that could achieve both (I am not an expert anyway) and I think I can't help you on that :(...

Comment: @user174174, Where do you see in the documentation the description of the smooth part?

Comment: @Royi in part 3 it says "The Smooth function will smooth fast-changing transients in a sound and is useful for removing glitches." however I just used enhance or as you say sharpening...

Comment: @ZaellixA tysm. and what if I only want the enhance (or sharpening)? that was doing a great job when I was digitizing cassette tapes... (DC remove, slight NR, enhance, normalize. and they were sound great). One other thing that I remember now is that the enhance was reducing the amplitude when applied, if that helps.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of "enhancing" algorithms and filters out there. Unfortunately, I can't really say what this specific "enhancement" filter could be doing. I'm definitely not an expert on such things and I am not sure I would be able to help even if I was. I believe there's lack of information (or examples for this case) to be able to deduce any useful information. Since I am not an expert on the field though I may be mistaken. I'm really sorry I can't be of any help here :(